# How to get 2 column user input in csv file through shell script

Tags: shell, csv

I want to read data from csv file through user input using shell script.

CSV file content below data
name, data, department1, id, "server name"

I have tried below command

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "Please enter a value which you want to get:"
read value
awk -v val="$value" '{print $val}' test1.csv    
echo $value


output: 
Please enter a value which you want to get: name
name
```

But here I want select another value from csv file.
Suppose If I select name and id then it should be display id and name.

Comment: Look into `csvgrep` from the `csvkit` package of utilities.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried with csvgrep command but still its not working.

Comment: Can we pass arguments in shell script and read data from csv file